# SQL: Create view using multiple tables and a cursor

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables : 'pc' and 'results'. the table 'results' contains so many results of every pc. 
I need to create view that contains all pc columns and the last result of every pc.
I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
select *
from pc,resultat where pc.code_pc=result.code_pc
order by code_resultat DESC limit 3
```

Do I have to use a cursor? if yes, how?

EDIT : `PC
ID_pc  name       x    y
1   Station1   1    1
2   Station2   2    2`

Result table:

```
code_rslt  ID_pc  parametre  value  date
1           1     ph         6      15/06/2015
2           2     ph         6.3    15/06/2015
3           1     ph         6.6    16/06/2015
4           2     ph         6.2    16/06/2015
```

I need a niew like this

```
ID_pc  name     x    y code_rslt  parametre  value  date
1      Station1 1    1     3        ph        6.6   16/06/2015
2      Station2 2    2     4        ph        6.2   16/06/2015
```

Comment: What does this have to do with a cursor?  What RDBMs is this?  what is the "last result of every pc"  can you provide your table schemas, sample data, and expected outcome of your query?

Comment: please check my post I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
Select p.*,r.*
from pc p
    inner join 
    Results r 
    on p.ID_pc = r.ID_pc
Where r.Code_reslt = (Select MAX(code_rslt) from results where ID_pc = p.ID_PC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
select r.id_pc, p.name, p.x, p.y, r.code_rslt, r.parametre, r.value, r.date
from (
    -- Get the max result per PC
    select max(code_rslt) as code_rslt
    from result
    group by id_pc
) maxPerId
inner join result r on maxPerId.code_rslt = r.code_rslt -- join maxPerId onto result table, to only include the maximum results
inner join pc p on r.id_pc = p.id_pc -- join on PC to get the PC information for the max results.
```

I'm unclear on what the `limit 3` was for in your example query as nothing like that was mentioned in your actual question - so hopefully this is something like what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I wish i could aprouve the two answers because this one result the probleme too. well thanks again you're a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve it with the following sample query:

```
select t.ID_pc, t.name, t.x, t.y, t.code_rslt, t.parametre, t.value, t.date from 
(
    select p.ID_pc, p.name, p.x, p.y, r.code_rslt, r.parametre, r.value, r.date from pc p 
    left join result r on r.ID_pc=p.ID_pc order by date desc
) t 
group by t.ID_pc
```

Note: If there is no result for a PC, it returns that row (for example station3) without any selected result, it means that the value for columns code_rstl,parametre,... would be null.

In this query, by default the 'group by' statement is looking for the top one record (In this case last result per each PC), so you don't need to call "max" SQL function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, please can u pease tell me how can I edit this query so that I can get all the data in pc table and if there is no result for a pc it must returns null ? thanks in advance